# Increase the /home mount size with space from root

Tags: centos

My /home directory is full. However, the `/` directory has 130G of available space.
Is it possible to resize the `/home` dir with space from `root` WITHOUT REBOOT?

OS: Centos 7

```
[$~]# parted /dev/sda "print free"
Model: VMware Virtual disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 268GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
        32.3kB  1049kB  1016kB           Free Space
 1      1049kB  1075MB  1074MB  primary  xfs          boot
 2      1075MB  64.4GB  63.3GB  primary
 3      64.4GB  96.6GB  32.2GB  primary               lvm
 4      96.6GB  268GB   172GB   primary               lvm
```

```
[$ ~]# df -hT
Filesystem              Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                devtmpfs  7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   tmpfs     7.8G  275M  7.5G   4% /run
tmpfs                   tmpfs     7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root xfs       196G   66G  130G  34% /
/dev/sda1               xfs      1014M  358M  657M  36% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home xfs        30G   30G   20K 100% /home <----- This
tmpfs                   tmpfs     1.6G   12K  1.6G   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                   tmpfs     1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
```

```
[$ ~]$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 268.4 GB, 268435456000 bytes, 524288000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000b68

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200   125829119    61864960   83  Linux
/dev/sda3       125829120   188743679    31457280   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda4       188743680   524287999   167772160   8e  Linux LVM
```

```
parted print free
WARNING: You are not superuser.  Watch out for permissions.
Error: Could not stat device print - No such file or directory.
Retry/Cancel? c
[$ ~]$ lsblk
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                             8:0    0   250G  0 disk
├─sda1                                          8:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot
├─sda2                                          8:2    0    59G  0 part
│ └─luks-0cad437f-3fa3-479e-8a94-fcbe333513d6 253:0    0    59G  0 crypt
│   ├─centos-root                             253:1    0 195.7G  0 lvm   /
│   ├─centos-swap                             253:2    0   5.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
│   └─centos-home                             253:3    0    30G  0 lvm   /home
├─sda3                                          8:3    0    30G  0 part
│ └─centos-home                               253:3    0    30G  0 lvm   /home
└─sda4                                          8:4    0   160G  0 part
  └─centos-root                               253:1    0 195.7G  0 lvm   /
sr0                                            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

```
[$ ~]# pvs
  PV                                                    VG     Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/mapper/luks-0cad437f-3fa3-479e-8a94-fcbe333513d6 centos lvm2 a--   <59.00g      0
  /dev/sda3                                             centos lvm2 a--   <30.00g <17.43g
  /dev/sda4                                             centos lvm2 a--  <160.00g      0
[$ ~]# vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
  centos   3   3   0 wz--n- <248.99g <17.43g
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't ***touch*** your `/boot` partition, resizing the root partition is possible. To do so boot from **another** system (with Gparted on the USB or external boot medium).  You will also need to zap the existing  swap space during that operation and rebuild it afterwards.  That does not represent much complication and is required to ensure that the two spaces `centos-root` and `centos-home` are contiguous during resizing.  Watch your `/etc/fstab` and _possibly_ rebuild it with new UUIDs for the two resized volumes and the new swap space ***before*** final reboot.

Comment: "Without reboot" NO, due to way disks, and disk synchronization works. The disk's partition table cannot be modified while any of its partitions is mounted. The only way to achieve this is by system shutdown.